# Test EAP-SIM with hostapd and wpa_supplicant

Tags: wpa-supplicant, hostapd

i am trying to test EAP-SIM with hostapd as AP and wpa_supplicant. 
I have built the hlr_auc_gw in hostapd for doing this.
hlr_auc_gw and hostapd start fine but when i start wpa_supplicant, nothing happens.
EDIT:
hostapd.conf is:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ieee8021x=1
eap_server=1
ssid=Test-EAP-SIM
eap_user_file=/tmp/hostapd.eap_user
eap_sim_db=unix:/tmp/hlr_auc_gw.sock
radius_server_auth_port=1812
radius_server_clients=/tmp/radius_clients
wpa=3
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP TKIP
```

wpa_supplicant.conf is:

```
network={
ssid="Test-EAP-SIM"
key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
eap=SIM
identity="1232010000000000"
password="90dca4eda45b53cf0f12d7c9c3bc6a89:cb9cccc4b9258e6dca4760379fb82581" 
}
```

hostapd still gives me the error:
wlan1: STA d6:f0:e3:1b:0f:f2 IEEE 802.1X: unauthorizing port
wlan1: STA d6:f0:e3:1b:0f:f2 IEEE 802.1X: authentication failed - EAP type: 0 (unknown)
wlan1: STA d6:f0:e3:1b:0f:f2 IEEE 802.1X: Supplicant used different EAP type: 18 (SIM)

What could i be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of changes that you need to do to wpa_supplicant conf file and also hostapd.
Changes that need to be done wpa_supplicant .config file are,

```
CONFIG_EAP_SIM=y
CONFIG_USIM_SIMULATOR=y
CONFIG_SIM_SIMULATOR=y
```

The configuration in wpa_supplicant.conf will look like below.

```
network={
ssid="hostapd"
key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
eap=SIM
identity="1232010000000000"
password="90dca4eda45b53cf0f12d7c9c3bc6a89:cb9cccc4b9258e6dca4760379fb82581" 
}
```

Note the first bit in identity is added as 1 for SIM.

On hostapd, the following changes are to be done.

```
CONFIG_EAP_SIM=y
```

hostapd.conf should have a line indicating milenage db like below.

```
eap_sim_db=unix:/tmp/hlr_auc_gw.sock
```

eap_user_file should be pointing to the correct user file.

The eapsuser file should have an entry for SIM as required.

hlr_gw_auc app should be started as follows:

sudo ./hlr_auc_gw -u -m ./hlr_auc_gw.milenage_db

Sample entry is mentioned below.

```
IMSI Ki OPc AMF SQN
232010000000000 90dca4eda45b53cf0f12d7c9c3bc6a89 cb9cccc4b9258e6dca4760379fb82581 61df 000000000063
```

Comment: Thanks Anand. I am now seeing the following error during authentication.
hostpad log:   
> wlan0: STA d6:42:02:9a:3e:6e IEEE 802.1X: authentication failed - EAP type: 0 (unknown)  
> wlan0: STA d6:42:02:9a:3e:6e IEEE 802.1X: Supplicant used different EAP type: 18 (SIM)  

Any idea what this error is referring to?

Comment: Mainly because the EAP-SIM method is not identified by the hostapd. Below I have mentioned some more changes.

Answer (score 0):

can you check the WPA/IEEE 802.11i configuration inside your hostapd configuration? List of parameters I have used is

1. wpa=3
2. wpa_passphrase=123456
3. wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK WPA-EAP
4. wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
5. rsn_pairwise=CCMP

Before starting hostapd.conf, it should be built and then milenage db should be started. Try this method.

Comment: Thanks Anand. I have all those settings (i have updated my original post with my hostapd and wpa_supplicant config files). I still see the same error (Supplicant uses different type). Anything else you can think of?

Comment: Can you tell me which version of wpa_supplicant you are using? Ideally 2.5 version with these changes should work.

Comment: I am using v2.6.
I enabled debug in wpa_supplicant log and see this:
    EAP-SIM: GSM authentication algorithm
    EAP-SIM: No GSM authentication algorithm enabled
    EAP-SIM: GSM authentication failed

it should pick it up from the milenage db file right?
Also, can you share your eap_user_file and radius_server_clients file?